# Cloning a document after accessing the Sender View using the Docusign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the **REST Docusign API v2** and I have some problems (seems a Docusign bug, but I'm unsure).

I have a website that has a button to view a Docusign document previously sent by us, this button creates an URL and performs the "[Post Sender View](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References%2FPost%20Sender%20View.htm)" resource call, which states:

> **Post Sender View**
>
> This provides a URL to start the sending view of the DocuSign UI. This is a one-time use login token that allows the user to be placed into the DocuSign sending view.
>
> Upon sending completion, the user is returned to the return URL provided by the API application.

The idea of this process is to show the Docusign GUI to view to document and perform some basic operations.

This is done correctly, but the problem I have, in such Docusign view there is a button, it says "Other actions" and after clicking on it, the option "Clone" is presented.

When clicking on "Clone", the session is expired, so the user is unable to perform any action. The message is:

> Session Ended
>
> Your session has expired due to an extended period of inactivity. To restart  the DocuSign session click the link in the email that initiated the session.
> For help: support@docusign.com

So, the point here would be: is there some fix for this? I'm doing something wrong?

I know the documentation says "*This is a one-time use login token that allows the user to be placed into the DocuSign sending view*"; but, if you decode to click the "Close" button, the session remains open and the user is able to work as usual.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Daniel - I just took a stab at trying to reproduce this. It seems that the 'other actions' dropdown is available only in the 'new docusign experience'. In my other actions menu, i have the following choices: save + close, discard, edit message/docs/recipients/advanced options.  If i hit the 'save and close' button i am taken to the returnURL provided on the API call with the &event=Save appended to the URL.  This 'sender view' should be used for DRAFT envelopes in my opinion - this is what you are doing yes?

Comment: Hi Luis,  

In mi case, I would like to preview a document previously sent, probably in a read-only mode.

Seems reasonable, the sender view would be only available for draft documents, but in this case, probably the "Clone" action shouldn't be present there (among others).

Do you know any method for previewing the document?.

I would give a try to the other resource: "Post Recipient View"

Many thanks!!!


Daniel.

Comment: Yes, if you use the post recipient view against an envelope which is completed, it will bring up a read only view of the document. There  are some account settings such as 'do not allow re-return access' or something to that nature which impacts this, but for all intents and purposes post recip view should do the trick.

Comment: Did that do the trick?

Comment: For any given embedded signer of an envelope, the triplet values of name (username), email, and clientUserID must be specified. You can interrogate these values by doing a GET against this envelope/<envelopeID>/recipients endpoing to double check you are using the correct values. In the GET you will notice that signer "name" is actually listed as "username"

Comment: Hi, at the and, I tried the "Post Recipient View", and it won't work, it is not readonly, in fact, it allows the sender to sign the document.
Many thanks for your help Luis.
Cheers.